# Is it normal for caulk to let go around my new home's tub and kitchen sink?

Tags: bathroom

Master bathtub caulking is already separating after 1 year after we bought this house brand new. It's also happening in the kitchen but nowhere else. Is this normal?

Comment: can you add a picture that shows it separating?

Comment: Welcome to DIYSE. Unfortunately, this type of "is it normal" question isn't really answerable due to the many reasons it may have happened, and it's not particularly helpful to you. Instead, show a photo of your particular situation, tell us everything relevant about the home, and we'll see if we can provide some useful assistance. If you're looking for legal advice, this isn't the right network.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes but with a caveat.

1. The caulk was not correct for the application.
2. Not enough caulk was used.
3. The caulk was an inferior make.
4. The caulk was placed "outside" the gap, not binding in it.
5. Incredibly high variances of temperature or humidity.
6. The caulk was messed with.   When cleaning an area you cannot just scrub hard against caulk.   Eventually you will loosen even the best caulk job by pushing/scrubbing on it.

Each of these could easily cause an issue within a year.  If the builder used a good silicone caulk which should have been used in these areas and that said caulk failed in that short of time it is most certainly one of the issues above or a combination of them.